# Do loop not working as expected

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to get rid of data in a list. Every three elements I want to delete. Example below:

```
list1 = {0., 0., 0, 4, 5, 6, 0., 0., 0, 10, 11, 12, 0., 0., 0, 13, 14, 15}
list2 = Drop[list1, {1, 1 + 2}];
list3 = Drop[list2, {4, 4 + 2}];
list4 = Drop[list3, {7, 7 + 2}]
```

This outputs:

```
{0., 0., 0, 4, 5, 6, 0., 0., 0, 10, 11, 12, 0., 0., 0, 13, 14, 15}
{4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}
```

Now I try and do the same with a 'Do' loop as below:

```
Do[list5 = Drop[list1, {j, j + 2}], {j, 1, 7, 3}]
list5
```

and I get:

```
{0., 0., 0, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 0., 0., 0, 13, 14, 15}
```

What should be changed? 
And yes, the data has both zeros with '.' and those without.

Comment: Perhaps you mean `tmp = list1; Do[
 tmp = Drop[tmp, {j, j + 2}], {j, 1, 7, 3}]; list5 = tmp`

Comment: Thanks, that works. So it doesn't work unless it gets immediately assigned to some other variable?

Comment: Probably more expedient to judiciously combine `Partition[]`, `Drop[]`, and `Flatten[]`…

Comment: @Magnet The reason it didn't work is that in the first input each list is constructed by dropping elements from **the previous** one, while in the `Do` loop it is always `list1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the length of your list is a multiple of 6, you can partition your list in successive groups of 6. The result is a matrix with 6 columns of which you want to delete the first three columns. That can be done with the Part-function. Finally we join the rows of the resulting matrix. That gives the result your are looking for.

```
lst = Range[30];
Join @@ Partition[lst, 6][[All, 4 ;; 6]]

(* {4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 16, 17, 18, 22, 23, 24, 28, 29, 30} *)
```

When the length of the list is not a multiple of 6, we pad it with a unique element such that the length of the list becomes a multiple of 6, do the same as above, and then remove the padded element.

```
lst = Range[34];
With[{a = Unique[Unevaluated[a]]}, 
  DeleteCases[
    Join @@ Partition[PadRight[lst,6 Ceiling[Length[lst]/6], a],6][[All, 4;;6]], a]]

(* {4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 16, 17, 18, 22, 23, 24, 28, 29, 30, 34} *)
```

This solution is independent of the elements you want to remove.

Comment: a bit cleaner if you partition by 3: `Partition[lst, 3][[2 ;; ;; 2]] // Flatten` or  `Partition[lst, 3, 3, {1, 1}, {}][[2 ;; ;; 2]] // Flatten`

Comment: @georg2079 Nice improvement, thanks!

Comment: This one works for me. Although, I ended up just using "Drop" three times in a row, to get rid of the extra data.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is removing (dropping) all the zero elements. If you think about it, this is the same as saving (selecting) all the values greater than zero. Thus

```
Select[list1, # > 0 &]
{4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}
```

gives the same output. Alternatively, you could use the "downsampling" function.

```
Flatten@Transpose[Downsample[list1, 6, #] & /@ {4, 5, 6}]
{4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}
```

Comment: This would probably work, but there is a tiny, tiny chance that the numbers I am interested in might be zero, as the integers in the above list are actually voltage readings from a moving transducer (the zero values are encoder feedback, I am taking 'stationary' data, and don't need the encoder values. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve removing the 0|0.

```
list1 /. {0 | 0. -> Sequence[]}
```

You could implement your recursive dropping of elements:

```
Fold[Drop[#1, {#2, #2 + 2}] &, list1, {1, 4, 7}]
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another..

```
 lst = Range[34];
 Delete[lst, {#} & /@ 
    Flatten[Table[ Range[0, 2] + i , {i, 1, Length@lst-2, 6}]] ]
```

possibly the best for speed if you have large lists.

Comment: This one works too. Thanks for the answer.